# Should I edit accepted, incorrect, negative-score answers?

Tags: discussion, answers

I was answering a question that was proposed as a duplicate of an older question. The older question is a good question (score 9), with a good answer (score 12)... but unfortunately the accepted answer is completely wrong, which is why it has lots of downvotes (score now -2 after I downvoted it, though split +6/-8) It's also five years old.

I suspect it's possible that this question may be linked to from other questions too, as it's something I could see being asked periodically. While the negative score on the accepted answer should obviously lead readers to scroll down to see the good answer... would it be legit to simply edit the wrong answer to say the correct thing, or even just link to the *real* correct answer?

Or is downvoting sufficient and I should just move on?

Comment: Edits are not meant to change answers, but to clean things up essentially. Such an edit would be clearly against the authors intent. So I would say just down-vote.

Comment: Edits are only meant to clarify the meaning of an answer, not to change it. So just down-vote the answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's what you can do in a situation like this :

- check and see if there are already any comments explaining why this accepted answer is incorrect

  - if there aren't any or you'd like to add more info on why it's incorrect leave your own comment
  - else don't leave a comment
- check and see if the OP left any comment saying this accepted answer worked for him/her.

  - if there aren't any, check and see if there's any comments asking the OP to reevaluate why he chose this as the accepted answer which is incorrect.

    - if there aren't any, check and see when the asker's last access date is

      - if the user has been active within the last week or so and will likely log back in again, then consider leaving your own comment asking why s/he accepted this answer that is incorrect and possibly state if there is a correct good answer to consider accepting instead
      - else don't leave a comment
    - else don't leave a comment
  - else don't leave a comment
- downvote the incorrect answer
- upvote the correct answer
- don't edit it, since you should not edit posts to change the author's intent like Spencer [mentioned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284433/should-i-edit-accepted-incorrect-negative-score-answers#comment147158_284433) in his comment

Comment: Looks like a solid flow chart to me.